# how can i set accounts state as logged-In in meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm using custom LDAP verification method to autenticate users for my application. What I have done is , i have users collection where i will first find the userId and if its true i will then call "ldapLogin" method which will authenticate users with LDAP server. Then i want to make the status of Meteor accounts as logged-In for the userId.
**login.js**

```
Template.login.events({
  'click #loginbtn': function (e) {
    username = $('.ui.form').find('#loginform_username').val();
    password = $('.ui.form').find('#loginform_password').val();
    var dn=<DN info>;
    var sys_password=<password>;
        if( username!="" || password!=""){
            var count=Meteor.users.find({username:username}).count(); //check for users already exist or not
            if(count==1){
                Meteor.call('loginLdap',dn,username,sys_password,function (error, result) {
                if (error) 
                    console.log(error.reason);

                    Session.set('userLogin',result);
            });
            var employeeLogin=Session.get('userLogin');
            if(employeeLogin){
                /*
                 *how to change the login status with only passing username 
                 */
            }           
        }else alert("User not found!\n Please check your username or contact your Manager.");
    }else alert("Username/Password field can not be empty!");
```

As i have verified password i want the login to be carried only passing username. Is this possible to do in Meteor Accounts package?

Answer (score 0):

You can login users using a Meteor.call with just the userId.  On the server, I do the following:

```
Meteor.methods({
'landingLogin'(userId) {
   const stampedLoginToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();
   Accounts._insertLoginToken(userId, stampedLoginToken);
   return stampedLoginToken;
  }
});
```

Then on the client:

```
Meteor.call('landingLogin', userId, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {

  } else {
    Meteor.loginWithToken(result.token);
  };
});
```